# Getting server timestamp in firebase while using functions

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

```
      // Create the user document
      const userRef = db.collection('Users').doc(uid)

      transaction.set(userRef, { 
        email,
        createTime : admin.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP,
      });
```

The placeholder `{.sv: "timestamp"}` doesn't get converted to a timestamp even on writing to the document.

Answer (score 1):

You are actually mixing up Firestore (e.g. `db.collection('Users').doc(uid)` or `transaction.set()`) and the Realtime Database (`admin.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP`).

With Firestore in a Cloud Function, to use "[sentinel values](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.FieldValue) that can be used when writing document fields", do as follows:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');

const FieldValue = require('firebase-admin').firestore.FieldValue;

//...
transaction.set(userRef, { 
     email,
     createTime : FieldValue.serverTimestamp()
});
```